# How to pass additional argument to controller method

Tags: node.js, express, controller

I am trying to pass additional argument to controller method (model name), but do not know how do it properly.
router js:

```
router.post('/strategies', CommonController.create('Strategy'));
```

controller:

```
const CommonServices = require('../services/CommonServices');

class CommonController {  

    create(model){
        console.log(model)
        return async function (req, res){
            try{
                let banner = await CommonServices.create(req.body);
                res.status(201).json({banner});
            }catch(e){
                let errors = CommonServices.handleErrors(e);
                res.status(400).json({errors});
            }
        }
    }

}

module.exports = new CommonController();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class CommonController {
  constructor(args) {
  }
  ..
  ..
}

module.exports = (args) => {
  return new CommonController(args);
}
```

Comment: thanks for response , can you show me how can I use that in router.js because now I have error, model is not defined

Comment: constructor(model) {
  this.model = model;
   }

 async index(req, res){
  console.log(this.model) // is undefined
  try{ 
   let strategies = await StrategyServices.index(req); 
   res.status(200).json(strategies);
  }catch(e){
   res.status(400).json(e);
  }
 }

Comment: const commonController = require("./CommonControler)

dep = { repo1 : Repo1() , ... }
app.use("/common", commonController(deps))